# Swift Popup how to pass value to PopupViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

i have two viewcontrollers: One which is just normal and the other one which i use like a Popup Viewcontroller. Now i need to pass a value to the Popup Viewcontroller but i cannot do it with the normal prepare for segue method. I start showing the Popup Controller like this:

```
  let popUpPreload = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "selectShoppingList") as! AddToListViewController

    self.addChild(popUpPreload)
    popUpPreload.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popUpPreload.view)

    popUpPreload.didMove(toParent: self)
```

so how can i transfer a value to my Subview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
popUpPreload.someProperty = ""
self.addChild(popUpPreload)
```

---

```
class AddToListViewController:UIViewController {
   var someProperty:String?
   //........ access someProperty inside viewDidLoad
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add subview within your first view controller as per shown in image. Add one label where you want to show your data I think you don't need to move to next viewController you can do this from single viewController as Add Sub view on same screen.

```
 @IBAction func buttonSave(_ sender: UIButton) {

            self.subViewLabel.text = textFieldName.text
            self.view.addSubview(subView)
        }


        @IBAction func crossBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
            self.subView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
```